Video Object Segmentation Accuracy
I have a question for measuring accuracy of video segmentation models. I see that these models use 2 measures of success generaly: Jaccard Index and Contour Accuracy. However, I don't really ever see code for the implementation of these methods. Does anyone know where I can find these? Thank you.
I have looked online, but can't really find code for these.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
